# Where do computational economists work

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, econometrics, statistics, computation

Does anybody know what kind of work or where computational economists end up working? It seems most end up in research...

Comment: I would expect that many private sector industries would love to hire computational economists. One example would be the investment firms. A computational economist could help such a firm develop and execute an algorithm for trading

Comment: I suppose people that define themselves as computational economists are mostly in research. However, in order to stay on top of current modelling techniques, many economists are adept at computational techniques. I think the right view for a person trying to imagine their future is that you can become either a pure theorist (a la Tirole), an empiricist, or a computational economist in some way...

Comment: Yeah i figured trading would be one of the jobs, it seems like data science is also one that pops up when I search computational economics

Comment: You can look who's hiring computational economists: http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=%22computational+economics%22&l=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most useful way of thinking of a Computational Economist is one that will be able to estimate economic models in a quantitatively meaningful way. This makes them very useful for central banks which have the need to study the macroeconomy quantitatively and also have the time and resources to invest in a computational economist...

Other ways to look at this question:

The conferences by the society for computation economics are all populated by academic economists or by central bank economists. [enter link description here](http://www.iscef.com/4/program-committee.html)

The job-board sites, mostly ask for data scientists when you type in computational economics. [enter link description here](http://www.indeed.com/q-Computational-Economics-jobs.html)

Commentators at the job econ rumors site claim two things: that computational economics is forever going to be the science of the future, but never the presently hot science.[enter link description here](http://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/computational-economics-2)

Comment: Note that there are lots of trolls on econ job rumors...

Comment: You are right, troll/truth ratio is pretty high.